Is it possible to use generic L2 solution for storing oracle data?
Various oracle use cases and security considerations require to store as much source data as possible. For example one might want to aggregate various sources or store historical data.
There are various solutions for not storing it all on L1. Chainlink AFAIU uses its own proprietary L2 solution. Other protocols propose to use custom Zero Knowledge Proofs logic for doing aggregation off-chain.
But can one use existent L2 generic solutions for similar purposes? Can one optimize oracle using public L2 rollup/validium (like Poly-chain or Optimism), or bootstrap custom L2 solution using some Open Source framework?

If you push the oracle data to some other chain, then the data is no longer available synchronously for the smart contracts. FIrst of all it is not going to work for many applications, but you are also going to pay the extra cost and time lag of interchain traffic that is often higher than L1 storage cost.

I mean could we off-load aggregated data from L2 to L1 via pull- or push-model? This would be similar to how Chainlink operates, but with public chain.
